# Odd wrong password behaviour with GRUB cryptodisk

Tags: grub2, luks

I have used `GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y` in `/etc/default/grub` to allow LUKS encryption of everything except my EFI partition, which I mount to `/boot/efi`.  This works fine.  The only admittedly small problem is that, if I happen to mistype my password, I don't get a second chance.  Instead, after 10 seconds or so, I'm left on a `GRUB rescue>` prompt.  Is there anything I can type at this prompt to try again, or must I power off and on?

Comment: the long wait for authentication is caused by a high default value of `iter-time`.  this can be changed using `cryptsetup luksChangeKey`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to just hit ctrl+alt+del to soft reset, but you do have to go through the POST again.

---

Another way to go, from the rescue prompt:

replace `hd0,gpt2` with the appropriate value for your machine - on my system it is shown as part of the password prompt. I'm using btrfs without any lvm (and no separate /boot partition), so your cryptomount and prefix parameters may differ somewhat from mine:

```
cryptomount hd0,gpt2
set prefix=(crypto0)/__active/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

Comment: on my system, the first argument can be replaced by `-a` (since i only have one encrypted device), and the second line can be omitted.